# XSLT transformation XML to HTML in browser doesn't work

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformation.xslt"?>
<data-xml>
    <limit type="integer">10</limit>
    <entries type="array">
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value type="integer">1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value type="integer">2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value type="integer">3</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</data-xml>
```

and such XSLT (transormation.xslt), which should transfrom my XML to HTML with table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/data-xml">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>XML data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <strong>Limit: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="limit"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="entries/entry"> 
                <tr>
                    <td> <xsl:value-of select="key"/> </td>
                    <td> <xsl:value-of select="value"/> </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML and XSLT files are successfully loaded, but instead expected HTML I see this:
[image: ugly plain text]

I tested this in FF in Chrome and received identical result.
But very ugly and incorrect result.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks you.

Comment: Try changing the `method` to `html`.

Comment: @JLRishe, you are truly right! It is so trifle, but it shatters my nerves. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was that the output method needs to be "html":

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
```